# How do I update the counting on the hash

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and I am trying to solve one of the challenges. Here is the question: I want to create a method called update_counting_hash that takes in two parameters. The first parameter is a hash, and the second is a key. The hash provided will have any number of keys, but all values will be integers. This method should do one of two things: increment an existing value based on the provided key parameter, or create a new key/value pair using the provided key, setting the value to 1

- given a hash an a key as parameters, return an updated hash
- if the provided key is not present in the hash, add it and assign it to the value of 1
- if the provided key is present, increment its value by 1

```
def update_counting_hash(hash, key)
 if hash[key] == {}
   return hash[key] = 1 
 else
   return hash[key] + 1
 end
end
```

These are some of the errors I have got.

got

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil

Failure/Error: expect(update_counting_hash({count: 5},:count)).to eq({count: 6})

       expected: {:count=>6}
            got: 6
```

Comment: To highlight a block of code indent it four spaces or select it and click on the {} icon above the code entry box. To highlight code that is within a sentence surround it with the backtick character (`), which often is a key below the escape key. A small example would be helpful. Please include the Ruby object that is the desired result. Also, by SO rules, if this is a homework problem you are asked to explain attempts you have made to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

The literal solution:

If you say the hash will only ever have integers, why would `{}` (an empty hash) ever be a value in your hash? One correct way to do it would be `if hash[key] == nil`. You could also say `if hash[key].nil?` or even `unless hash[key]` (since only `nil` and `false` are falsy in Ruby). A better way would be `if hash.key?(key)` 
— just in case someone snuck a `nil` (or `false`) into your hash.

The second error is `return hash[key] + 1`. After the first value was found, `hash[key]` will be set to `1` in the other `if` branch; so `hash[key] + 1` is correctly 2, the next time around. However, you never update the hash, you just return the value. So the third time, the value is still 2; and also the fourth, fifth and sixth time. You need to update the hash: `hash[key] += 1`.

Thirdly, you are returning the hash value, but your test seems to indicate you want the function to return the hash itself. If the requirement was to return the value, you could update the hash as before, then follow it by `return hash[key]` (though you can squeeze them both into `return hash[key] += 1`. In fact, you wouldn't even need `return` as it is the last value evaluated — Ruby automatically returns the last evaluation if end of the function was reached without an explicit `return`. However, to return the hash, something more is needed.

All together, your code could look like this:

```
def update_counting_hash(hash, key)
  if hash.key?(key)
    hash[key] += 1 
  else
    hash[key] = 1
  end
  hash
end
```

The Ruby way: use the default value.

```
hash = Hash.new(0)
hash["foo"] += 1
hash["foo"] += 1
hash["foo"]
# => 2
```

Comment: Also, this does not cover the test `expect(update_counting_hash({count: 5},:count)).to eq({count: 6})` which is what OP asked about. The method should return `hash` itself, AFAICT.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problem with your code (I have some comments below)

```
def update_counting_hash(hash, key)
 if hash[key] == {} 
   # Here you will check if the hash does not have the key instead of doing this
   return hash[key] = 1 
 else
   return hash[key] + 1
   # You should assign new value for the existing key first before returning its value 
 end

 # Finally, return your expected output here, the return keyword is not needed
end
```

You can check more about Ruby hash [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html)